# force table elements to fill parent width when display block is used

Tags: html, css

I have a table that for various reasons needs to have display block set. My understanding of display block was all elements within the display block element would have their width set to the parent width. My understanding is flawed, can someone explain why the header elements do not fill the width of the table?

```
  <div style="width:500px; background-color:grey">
    <table style="display:block; color:white;">
        <thead>
            <tr style="background-color:orange">
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test2</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr> 
                    <td>foo</td>
                    <td>bar</td
                 </tr>
                </tbody>
        </table>
     </div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vZeFs/)

Comment: Any particular reason you need it as block? Because this works fine http://jsfiddle.net/vZeFs/1/

Comment: Using `display: table` breaks the table layout, What are the `various reasons`?

Comment: I am running a javascript plugin that needs the tbody to have a fixed height when no elements are present.

Comment: Have you tried: <table width="100%">?

Comment: @Diodeus Doesn't work with `display: block;`

Comment: @gh9 If you're using JavaScript, you'd need to change the display type of `thead, tbody, tr` elements to `block` and adjust the width of the columns `th, td` via JavaScript

Comment: there isnt a css fix that i can apply without manupilulating the dom elements via JS?

Comment: A table is already a block element.

Comment: @Diodeus I know, but the OP said he/she is using a JS library which changes the display type of the table element to `block`, Hence setting the `width: 100%` won't work anymore because the table layout is broken. (default `display: table` has been overridden)

Comment: He can apply `table { display: table !important; }` if JS library is changing his display value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isnt a answer to this question. I eventually just re-wrote the table and modified the plugin. Thank you to the people which tried helping.